# Gradle task ProGuardTask can don't shrink some custom classes?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, shrink

Now I build and proguard a jar in a gradle task.  I do not want to shrink a specific class but expect to shrink others, because the class will be loaded dynamically, namely it's a entry.

I know a item `dontshrink` which will not shrink all.  But how to process a single or some classes?  Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the proguard documentation?  This is answered in detail.